# Как посмотреть затрачиваемые ресурсы программы?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В заданиях от яндекса всегда есть условия для задачи. Как посмотреть эти данные например в Visual Studio? То есть память которая используется программой и время выполнения

Comment: на самом деле это имеет мало смысла. Эти параметры лучше оценивать в порядках. Адекватное решение задачи обычно требует ресурса в несколько раз меньше, чем ограничения. Почему имеет мало смысла - потому что железо на сервере и у вас отличается. Плюс нужен тот же компилятор с теми же опциями. Память можно посмотреть в диспетчере задач (добавьте задержку, чтобы не закрылось раньше времени).

Comment: @pavel Я с вами полностью согласен, однако к большому сожалению условия такие какие есть, это всё зависит от многих факторов, но задача из яндекса это как пример требуемых условий к программе, из чего у меня возникает логически вопрос как можно измерять эти требования. То есть например составить программу и посмотреть затрачиваемые ресурсы и если например в случае неудовлетворению условию модифицировать программу

Comment: вы под windows работаете как я понимаю. Память через диспетчер, я уже написал. Время можно например замерять через `auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); //code auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;`

Comment: в реальных тест системах используются специальные утилиты для этого. пример утилиты под линукс - time или timeout. а память ограничивается через soft limit

Comment: Debug -> Windows -> Show diagnostic tools

Comment: VS19 : Отладка -> Профилировщик производительности. Там много всего